# Mapbox NavigationController not showing route

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox

I'm using mapbox for navigation, My issue is when I present `NavigationController` sometimes the route is not showing in the map and when i close my app and reopen it, it's working fine.

Here is My code to showing the `NavigationController`:

```
let options = NavigationRouteOptions(waypoints: [origin, destination], profileIdentifier: MBDirectionsProfileIdentifier.automobile)

 Directions.shared.calculate(options) { (waypoints, routes, error) in

        if error != nil {

        }                
        guard let route = routes?.first else {
               print("Empty")
               return
        }

self.navViewController = NavigationViewController(for: route, directions: Directions.shared, styles: [CustomNightStyle()], locationManager:  NavigationLocationManager())  //NavigationLocationManager()  SimulatedLocationManager(route: route)

self.navViewController?.mapView?.delegate = self
self.navViewController?.delegate = self

self.wayPointLocation.append(origin)

self.addChildViewController(self.navViewController!)

self.navigationView.addSubview((self.navViewController?.view)!)

self.navViewController?.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

**Route not showing : But route directions and arrows are showing in map**

[image]

[image]

> My Question is : how i can identify that route is displayed or not?

Comment: Why aren't you checking the error parameter?

Comment: @Magnas error param is nil, i get route data as well, but route not showing in map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it :).

After navigation map is loaded, I get event from `MGLMapViewDelegate` delegate method `mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap`.

And inside `mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap` i checked mapview style layer property.

```
if let _ = vcNav.mapView?.style?.layer(withIdentifier: "routeLayer") {
            print("Found ::")
} else {
         print("Not Found ::")

         vcNav.mapView?.removeRoutes()
         vcNav.mapView?.removeWaypoints()
         vcNav.mapView?.showRoutes([vcNav.route])
         vcNav.mapView?.showWaypoints(vcNav.route)
}
```